# Big O. not sure how the update on a for loop affects it

Tags: java, big-o

I'm a bit confused as to how an update on a for loop affects the BIG O

on a code like this :

```
  public static void bigO(int n){
    for(int i=n; i>1; i=i/2){
      for (int j=n; j>1; j=j/2){
        sum++;
      }
    }
  }
```

I'm not sure how the update `(j=j/2)` would affect it.

Answer (score 3):

The two `for` loops are independent of each other, so the total complexity should roughly be the product of the complexities of the two loops.  Each loop is `O(lgN)`, where `lg` means "log base 2."  So, multiplying this together yields `O(lgN*lgN)` for the overall complexity.

To understand better whence `O(lgN)` is, consider an input value of `n=16`.  The outer `for` loop in `i` would then have these iterations:

```
i  | iteration #
16 | 1
8  | 2
4  | 3
2  | 4
```

`lg(16)` in fact equals 4, because `2^4 = 16`, so this confirms the complexity which we expect.  You may also test other `n` values to convince yourself of this.  The inner loop in `j` behaves the same way, and is independent of the outer loop in `i`.

Comment: Log bases aren't written in normal big-O notation, since logs with different bases can be converted by applying a constant factor, and constant factors are removed. So you can write "O(log(n)^2)"

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt While you might be right, I would rather leave my answer as is, because we would still start with log base 2, which is the actual observation coming from the code.